# NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "javax.swing.JButton.getIcon()" is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Im trying to make a tictactoe blackout game where you have to fill everything with a specific icon. everything is doing well but the problem im having is when checking if the player has won by

```
if(buttons[0].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[1].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[2].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[3].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[4].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[5].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() 
   && buttons[6].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[7].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[8].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[8].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[10].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[11].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[12].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[13].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[14].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[15].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[16].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[17].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[18].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[19].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[20].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[21].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[22].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape() && buttons[23].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()
   && buttons[24].getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape()) {
                                System.out.println("Win");
                            }else {
                                System.out.println("Not Yet");
                            }
```

I even tried this and have the same error

```
Arrays.stream(buttons).allMatch(button -> button.getIcon().toString().equals(PlayerSetting.getShape()))
```

This is how i initialized my buttons

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton();
            buttons[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(playerTurn == true) {
                        JButton Clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
                        int tries = PlayerSetting.getDie();
                        if(tries > 0) {
                            Clicked.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PlayerSetting.getShape()));
                            PlayerSetting.setDie(tries - 1);
                            System.out.println(Clicked.getIcon().toString() == PlayerSetting.getShape());
                            Clicked.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                        
                        if(tries == 1) {
                            for(JButton b : buttons) {
                                b.setEnabled(false);
                                doneBtn1.setVisible(false);
                                doneBtn.setVisible(true);
                                doneBtn.setEnabled(true);   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(playerTurn == false){
                        int tries = AiSetting.getDie();
                        if(tries > 0) {
                            JButton Clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
                            Clicked.setIcon(new ImageIcon(AiSetting.getShape()));
                            AiSetting.setDie(tries - 1);
                            System.out.println(tries);
                            Clicked.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                        
                        if(tries == 1) {
                            for(JButton b : buttons) {
                                b.setEnabled(false);
                                doneBtn1.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            gameFrame.add(buttons[i]);
        }
```

This is the error that is showing

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "javax.swing.JButton.getIcon()" is null
    at MainFrame$1.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:58)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Thank you in advance, Ive been stuck in this problem for 6 hours and i just cant get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to set `Icon` only when button is clicked. Instead of that, set it at the beginning when you create `JButton`.
Otherwise, when you perform checking and you get the icon it will be `null` because this object isn't created with a button.
You can set it after creating button e.g.:

```
JButton jButton = new JButton();
jButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pathToDefaultImage));
```

Comment: I wanted it to change icon after click cause im making a tic tac toe game where you have to fill every single button with the same icon. So initializing the icon at the beginning of the program is not a choice

Comment: So if you don't want to set default value, you can check `buttons[i].getIcon() != null` and if it's true, then compare what you set there.

Comment: Omg. you are right. What I did was set a white Icon on my buttons. and its working fine. I guess I was tired from programming that I didn't think about why it was null. Your comment made me realize that I needed to initialize a icon. Thanks Matt